# How do I calculate a function between each pair of rows of a group in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to calculate a function for a record with every other record in a group and then take the max of them for each record. eg:

```
product, city, value
a, 1, str1
a, 1, str2
a, 1, str3
a, 2, str4
a, 2, str5
a, 2, str6
```

suppose my function is calculating similarity in the strings, then I want to calculate similarity between str1, str2 and str1, str3 and give the max value as a new column for the first row. Similarity between str2, str1 and str2, str3 and give the max value as a new column for the second row and so on for each group of product, city.

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the function to do more concretely?  The string value seems to also be the value you want the max of, so I'm not clear what you want from the similarity / max value part of your question.  Perhaps if you game some actual examples of strings / values it would help.

Comment: i want to calculate the similarity between these strings and select the one that is the most similar to the value in a particular row

Comment: How would you score similarity?  E.g. is 'abc' most similar to 'abd' or 'abcd', is 'abc' most similar to 'aabc' or 'abcc'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Basically, we are looping through every row in each group and computing the similarity using SequenceMatcher between the value of that row and all other rows in that group and assigning the max value to the new column - This is here achieved by 2 lambda functions - one for the outer loop and the other for the inner loop

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 'str1'],
                   ['a', 1, 'st2'],
                   ['a', 1, 'str3'],
                   ['a', 1, 'str10'],
                   ['a', 2, 'str4'],
                   ['a', 2, 'str5'],
                   ['a', 2, 'str6']],
                  columns=['product', 'city', 'value'])

def func(grp):
    def match(id, val):    
        matches = grp.drop(id).apply(lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, x['value'], val).ratio(), axis=1)
        return max([x for i, x in enumerate(matches) if x])

    return grp.apply(lambda row: match(row.name, row['value']), axis=1)


res = df.groupby(['product', 'city']).apply(func).reset_index()
res['level_2'] = df['value']
res.rename(columns={'level_2':'value'}, inplace=True)

print(res)
```

Output:

```
  product  city  value         0
0       a     1   str1  0.888889
1       a     1    st2  0.571429
2       a     1   str3  0.750000
3       a     1  str10  0.888889
4       a     2   str4  0.750000
5       a     2   str5  0.750000
6       a     2   str6  0.750000
```